# Rails: how to count number of users?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

here is my models.

**User**
unit_id

**Unit**
block_id

**Block**
postalcode_id

**Postalcode**
neighbourhood_id

**Neighbourhood**
name

the relations is for all is top belongs to bottom

this is my current index.html.erb file, i wish to output the number of user in each neighbourhood.

```
<% provide(:title, 'Neighbourhoods') %>
<ul class="thumbnails">
    <% @neighbourhoods.each do |neighbourhood| %>
    <li class="span3">
        <div class="thumbnail">
            <div style="position:relative;">
                <%= link_to "Join", '#', class: "btn-join" %>
                <%= image_tag(neighbourhood.name+".jpg", alt: neighbourhood.name) %>
            </div>
            <h2 style="margin-bottom:0px"><%= neighbourhood.name.titleize %></h2>
            <% neighbourhood.postalcodes.each do |postalcode| %>
            <%= postalcode.blocks.map(&:block).join(", ") %>
            <% end %>
            <br>
            <%= neighbourhood.streetname.titleize %>
        </div>
    </li>
    <% end %>
</ul>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a Neighborhood `has_many` Users:

```
<%= neighbourhood.users.size %>
```

Note that counting is a relatively slow option, so you can optionally cache the number of users for speed using `counter_cache`:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :neighborhood, :counter_cache => true
end
```

Then in a migration:

```
add_column :neighborhoods, :users_count, :integer, :default => 0
```

Comment: Hi Alex, thanks for the quick response. My model doesnt have this relation, therefore the relation is neighbourhood -> postalcode -> block -> unit -> user. Is there a solution for this instead?? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like an awfully deeply nested set of associations. You may want to take a second look at your models and see if you can 'trim them down' a little. Maybe something like just have a User and Unit model, then add block, postal code and neighbourhood to Unit where you could do Unit.block, and Unit.postal_code...ect.

That being said with your current configuration (assuming correct associations of has_many/belongs_to) you should be able to do something like:

```
Neighbourhood.postal_code.block.unit.users.count
```

Good luck!

Comment: undefined method `blocks' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation:0x3fa0b60> cant work. I need it this way because one postal code might have many blocks

Comment: Post all of your models and their relations (has_one, has_many, belongs_to) so we know what you are currently working with.